# A simple htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How would I write a redirect rule that would let me use both http://www.site.com/rss and http://www.site.com/anydirectory/rss rather than http://www.site.com/rss.xml and http://www.site.com/anydirectory/rss.xml ?

I think I'm close, but for some reason, it's a Monday.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/rss.\xml/$ $1/rss [L]
```

Comment: Are @Sean and @Patrick on the right track? Do you want site.com/rss to redirect to site.com/rss.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want (you have them reversed):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?rss$ $1rss.xml [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but it looks like you intended to escape the `.` and that is done with `\.` instead of `.\`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/rss\.xml$ $1/rss [L]
```

Comment: Good catch on that Dennis, thank you. I was trying to escape it, but I must have mistyped. It's closer, but it's still not quite working.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the XML files, and you want to make URIs without the XML extension work.

```
# translate /rss to /rss.xml
RewriteRule ^rss$ /rss.xml 

# translate /anydirectory/rss to /anydirectory/rss.xml
RewriteRule ^(.+)/rss$ /$1/rss.xml
```

The code you tried suggests the opposite.

```
# translate /rss.xml to /rss
RewriteRule ^rss\.xml$ /rss 

# translate /anydirectory/rss to /anydirectory/rss.xml
RewriteRule ^(.+)/rss\.xml$ /$1/rss
```